# Fourier transform of "hyperbolically distorted" Gaussian / Bessel-type integrals

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, bessel-functions

Dear Math enthusiasts,

I'm trying to see if I can find an analytical expression for the Fourier transform of a Gaussian pulse $p(\tau) = {\rm e}^{-B\tau^2}$ that is distorted by a hyperbolic distortion of the form $\tau(t) = \sqrt{t^2+a^2}-a$. What I mean is I look at the function $p(\tau(t))$ and I try to transform this time $t$ to frequency.

This gives a Fourier integral of the following form $$G(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty {\rm e}^{-B\left(\sqrt{t^2+a^2}-a\right)^2} {\rm e}^{-\jmath \omega t} {\rm d}t.$$

Substituting the square-root doesn't help much, since it appears back when resubstituting $t$. I therefore tried to substitute $t = a \sinh(x)$ instead. Assuming I didn't make a stupid mistake, this gives $$G(\omega) = a\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\rm e}^{-B\left(a \cosh(x)-a\right)^2} {\rm e}^{-\jmath \omega a \sinh(x)} \cosh(x) {\rm d}x.$$

From [[*], eqn (2.3)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9C572E5CE44E9E0DE8630755DF99ABAC/S0013091505000490a.pdf/incomplete-bessel-functions-i.pdf) I know that $\int_{0}^\infty {\rm e}^{a \cosh(x)} \cosh(x) {\rm d}x = K_0(a)$ where $K_0(a)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind. As the integrand is symmetric, it should be no problem to extend this to $(-\infty,\infty)$. But still I'm not sure this is enough to solve the integral. Mathematica has refused to give me anything, but it's possible I used it in a wrong way. I tried manipulating the exponent to bring everything to one hyperbolic trig function, but I failed.

Any hints how I can proceed?

**edit**: Note that since $p(\tau(t))$ is even symmetric, $G(\omega)$ is real-valued and even and we can get rid of complex numbers altogether, i.e., $$G(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty {\rm e}^{-B\left(\sqrt{t^2+a^2}-a\right)^2} \cos( \omega t) {\rm d}t = 2 \int_{0}^\infty {\rm e}^{-B\left(\sqrt{t^2+a^2}-a\right)^2} \cos( \omega t) {\rm d}t.$$ Does this make it easier? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Firstly,
$$\begin{aligned}
&G(\omega,a,B)=a\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2B\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac ta\right)^2+1}-1\right)^2}e^{-ja\omega\frac  ta}\,\mathrm d\dfrac ta=a\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2B(\sqrt{t^2+1}-1)^2}e^{-ja\omega t}\,\mathrm dt,\\
&G(\omega,a,B)=aH(a\omega,a^2B),\\
\end{aligned}$$
$$H(\Omega,c)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-c(\sqrt{t^2+1}-1)^2}e^{-j\Omega t}\,\mathrm dt.\tag1$$

Let
$$\tau(t) = \sqrt{t^2+1}-1,\quad \tau\in[0,\infty),$$
so
$$t(\tau)=\pm\sqrt{(\tau+1)^2-1}=\pm\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau},\quad t\in(-\infty,\infty),$$
$$dt=\pm\dfrac{\tau+1}{\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau}},$$
$$\begin{aligned}
&H(\Omega,c)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{-1}e^{-c\tau^2(t)}e^{-j\Omega t}\,\mathrm dt
+\int\limits_{-1}^\infty e^{-c\tau^2(t)}e^{-j\Omega t}\,\mathrm dt\\
&=-\int\limits_{\infty}^0e^{-c\tau^2}e^{j\Omega\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau}}\dfrac{\tau+1}{\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau}}\,\mathrm d\tau
+\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{-c\tau^2}e^{-j\Omega \sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau}}\dfrac{\tau+1}{\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau}}\,\mathrm d\tau,
\end{aligned}$$
$$H(\Omega,c)=2\int\limits_0^{\infty} e^{-c\tau^2} \cos(\Omega\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau})\dfrac{\tau+1}{\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau}}\,\mathrm d\tau.\tag2$$
By parts:
$$\begin{aligned}
&H(\omega,c) = \dfrac2\Omega\int\limits_0^{\infty} e^{-c\tau^2}\,d\sin(\Omega\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau})\\
&=-\dfrac2\Omega e^{-c\tau^2} \sin(\Omega\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau})\bigg|_0^\infty
+\dfrac{4c}\Omega\int\limits_0^{\infty} \tau e^{-c\tau^2}
\sin(\Omega\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau})\,d\tau,\end{aligned}$$
$$H(\Omega,c)=\dfrac{4c}\Omega\int\limits_0^{\infty} \tau e^{-c\tau^2}\sin(\Omega\sqrt{\tau^2+2\tau})\,d\tau.\tag3$$
I don't see how to obtain the closed form of the integral $(3).$

At the same time, for $c<<\Omega$ the exponent in the formula $(1)$ allows polynomial approximation.

If $c\gtrsim\Omega,$ then the integral $(3)$ can be presented as $1D$ series, using the series expansion for sine expression [in the form of](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+sin(omega+sqrt(x%5E2%2B2x))+at+0)
$$\sin(\Omega\sqrt{x^2+2x}) = \sqrt{\dfrac x2}\Omega\left(2 + \dfrac{3-4\Omega^2}6 x + \dfrac{16 \Omega^4 - 120 \Omega^2 - 15}{240} x^2 + \dfrac{-64\Omega^6 + 1680\Omega^4 - 1260\Omega^2 + 315}{20160} x^3 + \dfrac{256\Omega^8 - 16128\Omega^6 + 90720\Omega^4 + 15120\Omega^2 - 14175}{2903040} x^4 + \dfrac{-1024\Omega^{10} + 126720\Omega^8 - 2217600\Omega^6 + 1663200\Omega^4 - 623700\Omega^2 + 1091475}{638668800}x^5 + \dots\right).
$$
([the asymptotic form of](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+sin(omega+x++sqrt(1%2B2%2Fx))+at+infty)
$$\sin(\Omega\sqrt{x^2+2x}) = \Omega{\cos((x+1)\Omega)\left(-\dfrac1{2x} + \dfrac 1{2x^2} + \dfrac{\Omega^2-30}{48x^3} - \dfrac{\Omega^2 - 14}{16x^4} - \dfrac{\Omega^4 - 540 \Omega^2 + 5040}{3840x^5} + \dfrac{\Omega^4 - 220 \Omega^2 + 1584}{768x^6} + \dots\right)} + {\sin((x+1)\Omega)\left(1 - \dfrac{\Omega^2}{8x^2} + \dfrac{\Omega^2}{4x^3} + \dfrac{\Omega^2(\Omega^2-168)}{384 x^4} - \dfrac{\Omega^2(\Omega^2-72)}{96 x^5} - \dfrac{\Omega^2(\Omega^4 - 1320 \Omega^2 + 59400)}{46080 x^6} + \dfrac{\Omega^2(\Omega^4 - 520 \Omega^2 + 17160)}{7680 x^7} + \dots\right)}
$$ is not so usable)

and [the integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Einfty%20x%5Ed%20e%5E(-c%20x%5E2)%20dx)
$$\int\limits_0^\infty x^d e^{-cx^2}\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac{d+1}2\right)}{2c^{\frac{d+1}2}}.$$
Length of the series can be selected, using the numeric experiments.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Interesting approach. I would need to consider an infinite number of terms for the series since I'm integrating $\tau$ to $\infty$, right? If I understand well, I could express $H(\Omega, c)$ via an infinite sum over $\Gamma((d+1)/2)/c^{(d+1)/2}$ with $d$ going from 3/2, 5/2, 7/2, ... and coefficients worked out accordingly. Would I be able to truncate this series somewhere safely? Can we say something on how rapidly its terms would be decaying for $d\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @Florian No doubt, you all understand well. BTW, Wolfram Alpha allows to get more terms series for sine expression and to get any estimation of the coeffitients. Partially, for $\Omega x >> 2$ the approximation [must use the series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+sin(sqrt(1%2B2%2Fx))+at+infty) for $\Omega x\sqrt{1+2/x}.$

Comment: @Florian And thank you for comments, asymptotic series added.

Comment: Thanks for the additions. I'm still confused with the integration limit. You're breaking the integral over $t$ in $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(-1,\infty)$. Then when you're substituting to $\tau$ the first runs from $-\infty$ to 0 and the second one from $-1$ to $\infty$. Why? When I substitute the limits for $t$, a -1 would become a $\sqrt{2}-1$? Since $t=0$ corresponds to $\tau=0$, shouldn't both integrals run from/to zero?

Comment: @Florian Thanks! This is a typo, fixed. $\tau$ must be non-negative.

Comment: Thanks! Though some more work is needed, your input gave some very useful pointers. I'll look into it and see how far I get. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @Florian You are welcome! (I hope that 2 parameters instead 3 leads to the detail solution. And the base $1D$ series allow to find required approximations.) I like the practical tasks, because the engineering is my life.